# C++ Binding non-static member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to pass a member function to another function in a nested class.

Passing a non-member function works well but passing the member does not compile:

*A.h:*

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
        B();
        ~B();
        doSomething();
    };

    class C
    {
        C();
        ~C();
        execute(function<void(void)> func);
    };

    C *myC;
    map<int, B> myMap;
}
```

*A.cpp:*

```
void A::member(int param)
{
    A::myMap[param].doSomething();
}

void nonA_func(int param)
{
    ...
}

void A::caller()
{
    myC->execute(bind(nonA_func, 42)); // OK
    myC->execute(bind(A::member, 42)); // COMPILER ERROR 1

    myC->execute(A::myMap[42].doSomething()); // COMPILER ERROR 2
}

A::main()
{
    myC = new A::C();
    // filling myMap

    caller();

    myMap.clear();
    delete C;
}
```

When compiling the following `COMPILER ERROR 1` occurs:

> ```
> error: invalid use of non-static member function  
>     myC->execute(bind(A::member, 42));
>                                ^
> ```

Actually defining `A::member` as `static` solves this problem, but then I can't access `myMap` anymore.
How can I bind the non-static member function?

---

I have also tried to pass the called function directly, resulting in `COMPILER ERROR 2`:

> ```
>  invalid use of void expression  
>      myC->execute(A::myMap[42].doSomething());
>                                        ^
> ```

Comment: Isn't `execute(function<void(void)> func;` missing a `)`? Spelling I assume...

Comment: A side note: `bind` is terrible, avoid it in favor of lambdas where possible. Definitely possible here.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe isn't *terrible* an overstatement?

Comment: @krzaq I won't go as far as terrible either, but with respect to `bind` I will quote the master: "No, no, no. Quicker, easier, more seductive." Although, to be honest not always that much quicker.

Comment: @krzaq not an overstatement according to some folks like Stephen T. Lavavej (it was in his lection at CppCon 2015 but I can't find it now).

Comment: Please do not post made up fantasy code, post **real code**. I added 2 of the missing semicolons while I was improving someone else's edit. But there was one I didn't see until after, and maybe more errors. How can we trust that this is the code you were having problems with, when it's full of irrelevant errors? Please only post real code.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I agree that there's no reason to use it over lambdas, I used to think that common type without type erasure could be useful i.e. for handler maps, but then I learned that the return type is magical and I can't know it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the `this` pointer to `bind` (or lambda). You can't use instance variables/functions without an instance.

```
myC->execute(bind(&A::member, this, 42));
myC->execute([this]{ member(42); });
```

Comment: That is a real good answer, thank you! Both are working fine.

Comment: For further readers: if `42` was a variable (like `i`), the lambda term would be `myC->execute([this, i]{ member(i); });`